# I want to change the class of one of the bubbles navigation to active

Tags: jquery, html

I want to change the one of the bubbles navigation to active when a div class is active with background image as style. Here is the sample code

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 var i=0; 
 var ba=['#screen0','#screen1','#screen2','#screen3','#screen4','#screen5','#screen6','#screen7','#screen8'];
 var id_0= $('#screen0');
 var id_1= $('#screen1');
 var id_2= $('#screen2');
 var id_3= $('#screen3');
 var id_4= $('#screen4');
 var id_5= $('#screen5');
 var id_6= $('#screen6');
 var id_7= $('#screen7');
 var id_8= $('#screen8');
 var id_9= $('#screen9');
 
 
 function checkk(){
  if($('#screen_1').attr('class', 'swiper-slide swiper-slide-active'))
 { 
  console.log('screen_1 is active');
  for(i=0; i<ba.length; i++){
   ba[i].removeClass('active');
  }
  $('#screen0').attr('class', 'active');
 }
 else if($('#screen_2').attr('class', 'swiper-slide swiper-slide-active'))
 { 
  console.log('screen_2 is active');
  for(i=0; i<ba.length; i++){
   ba[i].removeClass('active');
  }
  $('#screen1').attr('class', 'active');
 }
 else if($('#screen_3').attr('class', 'swiper-slide swiper-slide-active'))
 {
   console.log('screen_3 is active');
  for(i=0; i<ba.length; i++){
   ba[i].removeClass('active');
  }
  $('#screen2').attr('class', 'active');
 }
 else if($('#screen_4').attr('class', 'swiper-slide swiper-slide-active'))
 {
  console.log('screen_4 is active');
  for(i=0; i<ba.length; i++){
   ba[i].removeClass('active');
  }
  $('#screen3').attr('class', 'active');
 }
 else if($('#screen_5').attr('class', 'swiper-slide swiper-slide-active'))
 {console.log('screen_5 is active');
   for(i=0; i<ba.length; i++){
   ba[i].removeClass('active');
  }
  $('#screen4').attr('class', 'active');
 }
 else if($('#screen_6').attr('class', 'swiper-slide swiper-slide-active'))
 {console.log('screen_6 is active'); 
  for(i=0; i<ba.length; i++){
   ba[i].removeClass('active');
  }
  $('#screen5').attr('class', 'active');
 }
 else if($('#screen_7').attr('class', 'swiper-slide swiper-slide-active'))
 { 
   console.log('screen_7 is active'); 
   for(i=0; i<ba.length; i++){
   ba[i].removeClass('active');
  }
  $('#screen6').attr('class', 'active');
 }
 else if($('#screen_8').attr('class', 'swiper-slide swiper-slide-active'))
 {  console.log('screen_8 is active'); 
   for(i=0; i<ba.length; i++){
   ba[i].removeClass('active');
  }
  $('#screen7').attr('class', 'active');
 }
 else if($('#screen_9').attr('class', 'swiper-slide swiper-slide-active'))
 {  console.log('screen_9 is active'); 
   for(i=0; i<ba.length; i++)
   {
   ba[i].removeClass('active');
   }
  $('#screen8').attr('class', 'active');
 }
 }
 setTimeout(checkk(), 50);
  
 
 // Stall the bubble and content changing for just 300ms
});
```

```html
<div class="swiper-slider-area">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row appScreenshotCarousel-container swiper-container">
    <div class="screen-mobile-image"></div>
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
     <div class="swiper-slide" id="screen_1" style="background-image:url(img/screenshot_1.png)"></div>
     <div class="swiper-slide" id="screen_2" style="background-image:url(img/screenshot_2.png)"></div>
     <div class="swiper-slide" id="screen_3" style="background-image:url(img/screenshot_3.png)"></div>
     <div class="swiper-slide" id="screen_4" style="background-image:url(img/screenshot_4.png)"></div>
     <div class="swiper-slide" id="screen_5" style="background-image:url(img/screenshot_5.png)"></div>
     <div class="swiper-slide" id="screen_6" style="background-image:url(img/screenshot_7.png)"></div>
     <div class="swiper-slide" id="screen_7" style="background-image:url(img/screenshot_8.png)"></div>
     <div class="swiper-slide" id="screen_8" style="background-image:url(img/screenshot_9.png)"></div>
     <div class="swiper-slide" id="screen_9" style="background-image:url(img/screenshot_10.png)"></div>
    </div>
 
    <!-- Add Arrows -->
   </div>
   <!-- </div> -->
  </div><!-- End container -->
 </div><!-- End swiper-slider-area -->
  <div class="bubbles">
    <div class="bubble" id="screen0"></div>
    <div class="bubble" id="screen1"></div>
    <div class="bubble" id="screen2"></div>
    <div class="bubble" id="screen3"></div>
    <div class="bubble" id="screen4"></div>
    <div class="bubble" id="screen5"></div>
    <div class="bubble" id="screen6"></div>
    <div class="bubble" id="screen7"></div>
    <div class="bubble" id="screen8"></div>
  </div>
```

In the above snippet I have a phone modal as an image inside which a screenshot is placed and it changes to next image when user slides the active image to left or right. based on this action I want to change the bubble color to dark using Jquery. I have tried using div id and the change the bubble class to active but no result.

Comment: What swiper do you use? Is it [iDangerous Swiper](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/) or something else?

Comment: All the popular sliders have pagination feature already implemented, so you need no additional scripting, just a style change. Swiper mentioned above is one of best online and its pagination is simple, check [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/y7Lt5j6d/17/), it is a basic example.

Answer (score 0):

you have missed `$()` in `ba[i]`. check the code given below

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var i=0; 
    var ba=['#screen0','#screen1','#screen2','#screen3','#screen4','#screen5','#screen6','#screen7','#screen8'];
    var id_0= $('#screen0');
    var id_1= $('#screen1');
    var id_2= $('#screen2');
    var id_3= $('#screen3');
    var id_4= $('#screen4');
    var id_5= $('#screen5');
    var id_6= $('#screen6');
    var id_7= $('#screen7');
    var id_8= $('#screen8');
    var id_9= $('#screen9');


    function checkk(){
        if($('#screen_1').attr('class', 'swiper-slide swiper-slide-active'))
    {   
        console.log('screen_1 is active');
        for(i=0; i<ba.length; i++){
            $(ba[i]).removeClass('active');
        }
        $('#screen0').attr('class', 'active');
    }
    else if($('#screen_2').attr('class', 'swiper-slide swiper-slide-active'))
    {   
        console.log('screen_2 is active');
        for(i=0; i<ba.length; i++){
            $(ba[i]).removeClass('active');
        }
        $('#screen1').attr('class', 'active');
    }
    else if($('#screen_3').attr('class', 'swiper-slide swiper-slide-active'))
    {
            console.log('screen_3 is active');
        for(i=0; i<ba.length; i++){
            $(ba[i]).removeClass('active');
        }
        $('#screen2').attr('class', 'active');
    }
    else if($('#screen_4').attr('class', 'swiper-slide swiper-slide-active'))
    {
        console.log('screen_4 is active');
        for(i=0; i<ba.length; i++){
            $(ba[i]).removeClass('active');
        }
        $('#screen3').attr('class', 'active');
    }
    else if($('#screen_5').attr('class', 'swiper-slide swiper-slide-active'))
    {console.log('screen_5 is active');
            for(i=0; i<ba.length; i++){
            $(ba[i]).removeClass('active');
        }
        $('#screen4').attr('class', 'active');
    }
    else if($('#screen_6').attr('class', 'swiper-slide swiper-slide-active'))
    {console.log('screen_6 is active'); 
        for(i=0; i<ba.length; i++){
            $(ba[i]).removeClass('active');
        }
        $('#screen5').attr('class', 'active');
    }
    else if($('#screen_7').attr('class', 'swiper-slide swiper-slide-active'))
    {   
            console.log('screen_7 is active');  
            for(i=0; i<ba.length; i++){
            $(ba[i]).removeClass('active');
        }
        $('#screen6').attr('class', 'active');
    }
    else if($('#screen_8').attr('class', 'swiper-slide swiper-slide-active'))
    {       console.log('screen_8 is active');  
            for(i=0; i<ba.length; i++){
            $(ba[i]).removeClass('active');
        }
        $('#screen7').attr('class', 'active');
    }
    else if($('#screen_9').attr('class', 'swiper-slide swiper-slide-active'))
    {       console.log('screen_9 is active');  
            for(i=0; i<ba.length; i++)
            {
            $(ba[i]).removeClass('active');
            }
        $('#screen8').attr('class', 'active');
    }
    }
    setTimeout(checkk(), 50);


    // Stall the bubble and content changing for just 300ms
});
```

Comment: You can accept the answer if it resolves your issue.